# How can I retrieve the other table information?

Tags: sql

[image]

How can I get the RESULT using SQL?

Comment: SELECT R.PRJ_NAME,R.SELLER_IDX,SEL_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME ,R.BUYER_IDX ,BUY_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME  FROM RECORDS AS R JOIN COMPANY AS SEL_COMPANY ON R.SELLER_IDX=SEL_COMPANY.COMPANY_IDX JOIN COMPANY AS BUY_COMPANY ON R.BUYER_IDX=BUY_COMPANY.COMPANY_IDX

Comment: Show us what you have tried, this is an exercise in join

Comment: I tried to use UNION. but the double join is better. Thanks

Comment: I am just lost.  How many tables do you have?  What does `seller_idx` refer to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Multiple `JOINS` as follows:

```
select R.PRJ_NAME, R.SELLER_IDX, CS.COMPANY_NAME, R.BUYER_IDX, CB.COMAPY_NAME
  from RECORDS R 
  join PROJECT Ps on Ps.prj_name = r.seller_idx
  join PROJECT Pb on Pb.prj_name = r.buyer_idx
  join COMPANY Cs on Cs.company_idx = Ps.company_idx 
  join COMPANY Cb on Cb.company_idx = Pb.company_idx
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there are really two tables, `projects` and `companies`.  If so:

```
select p.proj_name, p.seller_idx, cs.company_name as seller_name,
       p.buyer_idx, cb.company_name as buyer_name
from projects p left join
     companies cs
     on p.seller_idx = cs.company_idx left join
     companies cb
     on p.buyer_idx = cb.company_idx;
```